# Get the unique result based on two columns swap value postgres

Tags: postgresql

40  Take two bread   10  Wash Room
10  Take one bread  40  Wash hand

I have multiple records like this. I want one record from above table based on Numbers condition only do not need to check other columns values (40,10 and 10,40) 
 
 Result can be 

 
40  Take two bread   10  Wash Room
 or 10  Take one bread  40  Wash hand 
 can we do it by using sql.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Have you made an attempt which isn't working?

Comment: I want one row for above table based on values(40,10 or 10,40)